# Was PreferenceFragment intentionally excluded from the compatibility package?

Tags: android, compatibility, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm looking to write preferences that can be applied to both 3.0 and pre-3.0 devices. Discovering that `PreferenceActivity` contains deprecated methods (although these are used in the accompanying sample code), I looked at `PreferenceFragement` and the compatibility package to solve my woes.

It appears, though, that `PreferenceFragment` isn't in the compatibility package. Can anyone tell me whether this was intentional?  If so, can I easily target a range of devices (i.e. < 3.0 and >=3.0) or will I have to jump through hoops?  If it wasn't intentionally excluded, can we expect a new release of the compatibility package?  Or is there another workaround that is safe to use?

Comment: This is my approach to solving the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076073/how-could-i-use-the-same-set-of-preference-screens-for-all-android-versions-from

Comment: Someone made a third party `PreferenceFragment` that you will forget is even there.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23553026/1747491).

Comment: Chris Banes addresses this [in a comment on his blog](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/#comment-1645984537).  He said that the reason is, `"Because most of Preferences' implementation is hidden, therefore impossible to backport without lots of hackery."`

Comment: See my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23553026/1747491). `PreferenceFragmentCompat` was recently added to the support library.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

> Discovering that PreferenceActivity contains deprecated methods (although these are used in the accompanying sample code)

The deprecated methods are deprecated as of Android 3.0. They are perfectly fine on all versions of Android, but the direction is to use `PreferenceFragment` on Android 3.0 and higher.

> Can anyone tell me whether this was intentional?

My guess is it's a question of engineering time, but that's just a guess.

> If so, can I easily target a range of devices (i.e. < 3.0 and >=3.0) or will I have to jump through hoops?

I consider it to be done "easily". Have two separate `PreferenceActivity` implementations, one using preference headers and `PreferenceFragments`, the other using the original approach. Choose the right one at the point you need to (e.g., when the user clicks on the options menu item). [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/FragmentsBC) demonstrating this. Or, have a single `PreferenceActivity` that handles both cases, as in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Prefs/FragmentsBC).

> If it wasn't intentionally excluded, can we expect a new release of the compatibility package?

You will find out when the rest of us find out, which is to say, if and when it ships.

> Or is there another workaround that is safe to use?

See above.

Comment: Cheers Mark.  I'd seen that you'd made comments about this in a couple places (android google group and your blog) but wanted a definitive answer (as far as one can get given the circumstances).

Comment: @James: Yeah, the rub will be in the preference XML definition, getting something that will work well as fragments and also concatenated together, since I'm not sure `<include>` works with preference XML. BTW, if you're a subscriber, the book update referencing this project was announced minutes ago.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not really sure what point you're trying to make here. You don't answer anything at all, merely comment/guess/refer to irrelevant external links that have nothing to do with the problem. The question is whether or not the omission was intentional, _without_ the compatibility version of PreferenceFragment there is no means of extending PreferenceActivity in the way you've described because if PreferenceFragment doesn't exist then neither do getSupportFragmentManager() or any of the other methods required to use fragments in the first place.

Comment: @JustinBuser: "The question is whether or not the omission was intentional" -- the only people who can answer that work for Google. You are welcome to get a job at Google to try to find out. "there is no means of extending PreferenceActivity in the way you've described" -- you are welcome to download the code that I linked to.

Comment: @JustinBuser For the record, Mark did answer my question. That's evident from me accepting his answer.

Comment: I downloaded the latest "Support" package and still no PreferenceFragment ! #disappointed

Answer (score 21):

The subtle implication of the answer from @CommonsWare is that - your app must choose between the compatibility API or the built-in fragment API (since SDK 11 or so).  In fact that's what the "easily" recommendation has done.  In other words, if you want to use PreferenceFragment your app needs to use the built-in fragment API and deal with the deprecated methods on PreferenceActivity.  Conversely, if it's important that your app use the compat. API you will be faced with not having a PreferenceFragment class at all.  Thus, targeting devices is not a problem, but the hoop-jumping happens when you have to choose one or the other API and thus submit your design to unforeseen workarounds.  I need the compat. API so I'm going to create my own PreferenceFragment class and see how that works.  In the worst case scenario I'll just create a normal (fragment) layout and bind the view components to the sharedprefs manually...ugh.

EDIT:
After trying and looking at the code at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.java?av=h -- creating my own PreferenceFragment isn't going to happen.  It appears the liberal use of package-private in PreferenceManager instead of 'protected' is the main blocker.  It really doesn't look like there's any security or really good motivation to have done that and it isn't great for unit-testing but oh well...less typing I guess...

EDIT v2:
Actually it did happen and it worked.  It was definitely a headache to make the code work with the Compatibility API JAR.  I had to copy about 70% the com.android.preference package from the SDK to my app and then wrestle with typically mediocre-quality Java code in Android.  I used v14 of the SDK.  It would have been much easier for a Goog engineer to do what I did, contrary to what I've heard some lead Android engineers say about this topic.

BTW - did I say "targeting devices is not a problem"?  It totally is...if you use com.android.preference you are not going to be able to swap out with the Compatibility API without major refactoring.  Fun log!

Comment: Let me be more direct.  If all you care about is targeting Honeycomb and higher (which has how much market share?) then vote for the answer from @Commonsware!  If you care about the majority of Android devices on the market today you should read through my response.

Comment: would you be willing to share how you did this? I'm running into exactly the same problem, only my PreferenceActivity has to use Loaders and therefore I **must** use the compatibility library.

Comment: @Tenacious I like your investigation - well done. However, I feel someone should set the record straight on your first comment there - Commonsware's code will work on pre & post HC devices - try it first before making comments like that. The thing you need to realise is the late binding used at runtime to support previous devices. The version check at runtime takes care of supporting both families of OS - this is a common Android pattern (not one I like - but one that is important for Android developers to learn & become familiar with)... So to future readers - don't dismiss either approach.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier but Commonsware's method is not proper if you need preferences inside DrawerLayout

Answer (score 16):

Building upon CommonsWare's answer as well as Tenacious' observations, I have come up with a single descendant class solution capable of targeting all current Android API versions with minimal fuss and no code or resource duplication.  Please see my answer to the related question over here:
[PreferenceActivity Android 4.0 and earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186697/preferenceactivity-android-4-0-and-earlier/11336098#11336098)

or on my blog:
http://www.blackmoonit.com/2012/07/all_api_prefsactivity/

Tested on two tablets running 4.0.3 and 4.0.4 as well as a phone running 4.0.4 and 2.3.3 and also an emulator running 1.6.

Answer (score 10):

See [PreferenceFragment-Compat](https://github.com/Machinarius/PreferenceFragment-Compat) from Machinarius.  It was easy to drop in with gradle and I forget that it's even there.

`compile 'com.github.machinarius:preferencefragment:0.1.1'`

**Important Update:** The [latest revision](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html?utm_campaign=ADP-protip-827&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=plus&linkId=16598683#v7-preference) of the `v7 support library` now has a native [PreferenceFragmentCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html?utm_campaign=ADP-protip-827&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=plus&linkId=16598687).

Answer (score 10):

On August 2015 Google released the new [Preference Support Library v7](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-preference).

Now you can use the [PreferenceFragmentCompat](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-preference) with any `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity`

```
public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

You have to set `preferenceTheme` in your theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  ...
  <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
</style>
```

In this way you can customize the `preferenceTheme` to style the layouts used for each preference type without affecting other parts of your Activity.

Comment: I think you miss a function : onCreatePreferences

Comment: This saved my day! I wonder why isn't this visible in Android Studio's Project Structure...?? BTW you have a typo in your code. Should be "extends PreferenceFragmentCompat"

Answer (score 7):

Tenacious's answer is correct, but here are some more details.

The reason you can't "create a normal layout and bind the view components to the sharedprefs manually" is that there are some surprising omissions in the android.preferences API. PreferenceActivity and PreferenceFragment both have access to critical non-public PreferenceManager methods, without which you can't implement a preference UI of your own.

In particular, to construct a Preference hierarchy from an XML file you need to use a PreferenceManager, but all of PreferenceManager's constructors are either package-private or hidden. The method of attaching the Preference onClick listeners to your activity is also package-private.

And you can't work around this by sneakily putting your implementation in the android.preferences package, because non-public methods in Android APIs are actually omitted from the SDK. With a bit of creativity involving reflection and dynamic proxies, you can still get at them. The only alternative, as Tenacious says, is to fork the entire android.preference package, including at least 15 classes, 5 layouts, and a similar number of style.xml and attrs.xml elements.

So to answer the original question, the reason Google didn't include PreferenceFragment in the compatibility package is that they would have had exactly the same difficulty as Tenacious and myself. Even Google can't go back in time and make those methods public in the old platforms (though I hope they do that in future releases).

Answer (score 2):

My app target is API +14 but due to using support library for some fancy navigation, I couldn't use the `android.app.Fragment` and had to use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, but I also needed to have `PreferenceFragment` in place without large changes to code behind.

So my easy fix for having both worlds of support library and `PreferenceFragment`:

```
private android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment;
private android.app.Fragment nativeFragment = null;

private void selectItem(int position) {
    fragment = null;
    boolean useNativeFragment = false;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new SampleSupprtFragment1();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new SampleSupprtFragment2();
        break;
    case 2:
        nativeFragment = new SettingsFragment();
        useNativeFragment = true;
        break;
    }
    if (useNativeFragment) {
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, nativeFragment).commit();
    } else {
        if (nativeFragment != null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(nativeFragment)
                .commit();
            nativeFragment = null;
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed integrate Preferences into application's design and keep support for 2.3 android. So I still needed PreferencesFragment.

After some search I found [android-support-v4-preferencefragment](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment) lib. This lib save a lot of time for copying and refactoring original PreferencesFragment as Tenacious said. Works fine and users enjoy preferences.