# Building Compatibility PreferenceFragment on Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, compatibility, preferenceactivity

My android application is using the compatibility library quite heavily (`Loaders` in particular). I need to be able to use compatibility components everywhere, including my `PreferenceActivity`. Sadly, the support library does not include a fragment-based `PreferenceActivity`, nor the `PreferenceFragment` class.

I'm toying with the idea of making my own PreferenceFragmentActivity and CompatPreferenceFragment (basically what Google neglected to do). Others, including some on StackOverflow, have mentioned accomplishing this exact thing, so I am openly asking for help of any kind -- guidance, tips, suggestions, code samples (if you are willing and able to share), or whatever else you deem relevant to this problem.

If someone can also direct me to the site where people file feature requests for Android, I'd like to add my name to the list of folks who want Google to address this in a future release of the support library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternatives to PreferenceFragment with android-support-v4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783368/alternatives-to-preferencefragment-with-android-support-v4)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Was PreferenceFragment intentionally excluded from the compatibility package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501431/was-preferencefragment-intentionally-excluded-from-the-compatibility-package)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at Fr4gg0r's implementation of `PreferenceFragment` using reflex at 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1363906

Comment: This is indeed what I resorted to using last week.

Answer (score 0):

See the [latest revision](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html?utm_campaign=ADP-protip-827&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=plus&linkId=16598683#v7-preference) of the `v7 support library`, which introduced a [PreferenceFragmentCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html?utm_campaign=ADP-protip-827&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=plus&linkId=16598687).