# Combining own BaseActivity and PreferencesActivity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I have a BaseFragmentActivity that all my activities extend. I would like to createa PreferencesActivity and take advantage of Androids preferences.xml capabilities, but obviously I cannot extend both classes.

I know newer APIs provide the use of PreferenceFragments but I want to offer support to legacy Android versions (from 2.3 and above).

How can I make use of the Preferences structure and extend my own base class (which has a few functionalities I need for all activities).

Answer (score 1):

Seems it's not possible to use `PreferenceFragment` now on older versions ([here some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783368/alternatives-to-preferencefragment-with-android-support-v4) discussion about it). However, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825205/building-compatibility-preferencefragment-on-android) some [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1363906) to xda-developers for creating Your own for older versions (but it's pretty hacky).