# PreferenceFragment with v4 Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-support-library, preferencefragment

In my application I am using v4 support library to display user preferences in a `ViewPager` with tabs. 
Until now I was using some custom `Fragment` that reproduces what `PreferenceFragment` does.

For instance, there are some suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783368/alternatives-to-preferencefragment-with-android-support-v4).

After updating all my Android SDK to the latest versions, these custom `Fragments` stopped working, in particular they seem to fail this method invocation by reflection:

```
static PreferenceScreen inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager manager,
        Activity activity, int resId, PreferenceScreen screen) {
    try {
        Method m = PreferenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("inflateFromResource", Context.class, int.class, PreferenceScreen.class);
        m.setAccessible(true);
        PreferenceScreen prefScreen = (PreferenceScreen) m.invoke(manager, activity, resId, screen);
        return prefScreen;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Couldn't call PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource by reflection", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Since nobody can change exposure of the method in the APIs, is it still possible to create a `PreferenceScreen` starting from a XML file?

Comment: did you found any solution?

Comment: I stopped using that fragment