# Using Tabs inside android.app.Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

How can I create a Fragment with tabs on the top, hosting other Fragments?

I previously used `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` but switched to `android.app.Fragment` because of the `PreferenceFragment` class. My code was:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabs,container, false);


        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentb").setIndicator("Fragment B"),
                FragmentB.class, null);

        return rootView;
    }
```

But this don't work anymore because `setup` require a v4-FragmentManager.

Any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SubinSebastian [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20727515/4878298) :

Add the following project as a library project to your application.

https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment

This solution is better than all other solutions. Add this project as a library project to your workspace. You can keep everything including your fragment transaction as it is and when importing the PreferenceFragment do it like the following.

```
import android.support.v4.preference.PreferenceFragment;
```

instead of

```
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
```