# PreferenceFragment with AppCompatActivity Android

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

I'm trying to create a Preferencefragment or a PreferenceActivity using the tabs. Actually i can't do it and my code is simply:
The MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FirstFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new SecondFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThirdFragment(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

and one of the fragment

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment{
    public FirstFragment () {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

        return view;
    }

}
```

As you can see it's empty. Now, i need replace the fragments with the preferencefragment. But i can't understand how implement them with tabs. How can i do it?

Answer (score 3):

Not too long ago, this [would not have been possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783368/alternatives-to-preferencefragment-with-android-support-v4), due to PreferenceFragments not working well with the support library.  With the latest version of the support v7 library, we now have the [PreferenceFragmentCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html) class, which will work in an AppCompatActivity, and will also work with your ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter.

Since you're using support library fragments with `android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`, this is the only option with your current configuration.
Note that it is possible to use a TabLayout with non-support fragments, however you have to use the `android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` class, which does allow use of non-support fragments.

So to keep your current configuration and make it work, make your PreferenceFragment extend PreferenceFragmentCompat:

```
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat; 
import android.view.View; 

public class MySettingsPrefFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat { 

    public MySettingsPrefFragment() { 
        // Required empty public constructor 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.fragment_settings_pref); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) { 

    } 
}
```

Add a new tab that corresponds to your PreferenceFragment:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FirstFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new SecondFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThirdFragment(), "THREE");
    adapter.addFragment(new MySettingsPrefFragment(), "SETTINGS"); //added
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And, that should be it!

Comment: Nice explanation, after work i'll try. Thanks anyway! I'll accept the answer as soon as possibile

Comment: @End.Game Does it work? Does it require compile SDK 23?

Comment: I am trying to use Fragment Activity and Preference Fragment Together but app crashing while coming back to Fragment activity from Fragment Preference. Is this combination workable? can u guide.