# Preference Fragment with android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

How to use preference fragment with android.support.v4.app.Fragment?
I tried to use android.preference.PreferenceFragment but I got an error: Wrong 2nd argument type/

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SettingsFragment());
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
```

SettingsFragment is the preference fragment

What can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By my knowledge `PreferenceFragment` is not supported in the `android.support.v4` library.

You can however use `PreferenceFragmentCompat` from the support-v7 library.

If it really has to work with the support-v4 library, I would recommend adding the following project as a library project to your application as suggested by [this old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783368/alternatives-to-preferencefragment-with-android-support-v4).

https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment