# Android Transaction with PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I'm using a `FragmentTransaction` to replace a fragment in a container like this:

```
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out).replace(R.id.container, fragmentToShow).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

The problem is that a `PreferenceFragment` can not be converted to support v4 fragment. How can I use a `PreferenceFragment` like that?

Comment: This link might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783368/alternatives-to-preferencefragment-with-android-support-v4

Comment: I saw that but I can't add the PreferenceFragmentCompat.. it says "The import android.support.v7.preference cannot be resolved" even though the support appcompat is being used by me

Comment: Add appcompact v7.  dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
}

Comment: where do I do that? I don't use gradle. working with eclipse

Comment: This link help you how to add it in eclipse. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998368/the-import-android-support-v7-cannot-be-resolved

Answer (score 8):

I did the same problem and I solved in those steps:

1. Add to gradle file dependencies this line 
   **compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.3.0'**
2. Extends your SettingFragment with 
   **'PreferenceFragmentCompat'**
3. Import in your class 
   **import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;**