# How can use getSupportFragment in Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I want use `Fragment` in `activity` and for this issue I want use `getSupportFragment`.
I have written the code below in `activity` for showing the  `fragment` :

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_containerone, settingsFragment, "Setting");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**my SettingFragment codes:**

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

import in.nouri.cameraalways.R;
import in.nouri.cameraalways.Service.OverlayService;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = null;

    SharedPreferences defaultSharedPreference;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            defaultSharedPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        } else {
            defaultSharedPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        }
        Log.d("defaultpPref", defaultSharedPreference.getAll().toString());
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        listener = (SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener) activity;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        listener = (SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        listener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onResume");
        super.onResume();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);

        CheckBoxPreference preference_enabled = (CheckBoxPreference) this.findPreference(getString(R.string.key_pref_enabled));
        preference_enabled.setChecked(OverlayService.isRunning());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

But when using the code above in `Activity` **(for use fragment in activity)** it shows me this message:

[image: Please see image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: try using this import `import android.support.v4.preference.PreferenceFragment;` instead of `import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
`

Comment: @PavneetSingh, thanks but not found import `android.support.v4.preference.PreferenceFragment;`

Comment: try this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783368/alternatives-to-preferencefragment-with-android-support-v4

Comment: @dfgb see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SettingsFragment is subclassing the `android.app.Fragment` class instead of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Change the import statement in the fragment and you are good to go.

**Update**
Instead of `import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;`
in your Settings fragment use `import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;`. 
Note that it requires `compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.2.1'`
in your app.gradle file

Comment: Please see my imports in settingFragment : import `android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

import in.nouri.cameraalways.R;
import in.nouri.cameraalways.Service.OverlayService;`

Comment: Thanks my friend for your answer. but when added this imports and compile file when running application show me this error and show Force close error. Error image : http://uupload.ir/files/9n0z_34.jpg    please see this image and help me. please

Answer (score 0):

Create Instance of your SettingsFragment Like this in your SettingsFragment:

`public static SettingsFragment getInstance() {
        return new SettingsFragment ();
    }`

Call it into your activity like this: 
`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().Add(R.id.container, PrivacyFragment.getInstance()).commit();`