# DialogFragment in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, android-dialogfragment

I have defined `dialogfragments` (because Android documentation says that it is better and indeed it is) but now I want to use it in `PreferenceActivity`.

The problem is that I cannot use `getSupportFragmentManager()` there and I cannot use PreferenceFragment since it doesn't work with compatibility library. Looks like a road block scenario.

Can anyone advise on this?

Comment: I've never done this, but maybe you can use a PreferenceFragment instead of a FragmentActivity? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html

Comment: I cannot use PreferenceFragment since it is not available in compatibility library

Comment: I've also spent some time on this.  The PreferenceActivity.onPrepareDialog() states that the DialogFragment should be available with the compatibility package.  But I think that is a mistake.  There is simply no FragmentManager available with the PreferenceActivity.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, PreferenceFragment is not in the android compatibility package and unfortunately there is no clean way around this. For my own personal project, I had to adapt an implementation off of Android's source code:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.java

The answers to this question have some great suggestions:
[Was PreferenceFragment intentionally excluded from the compatibility package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501431/was-preferencefragment-intentionally-excluded-from-the-compatibility-package)