# How can I show a preferences screen on older Android devices i.e. Gingerbread and Froyo?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, actionbarsherlock, android-preferences

I need to show a preferences screen from my application. I've managed to implement this and it works on Ice-Cream Sandwich and newer devices but doesn't work on older devices like Gingebread and Froyo. I'm using ActionBarSherlock as a compatibility library to support older devices.

Here's the code for the `Activity` that contains the preference screen:

```
public class Settings extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new Preferences())
                .commit();
    }

}
```

This is the sample code from my activity that invokes the preferences screen:

```
public class Trend extends SherlockActivity {

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem itmMenuitem) {
        if (itmMenuitem.getItemId() == R.id.search) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Settings.class));
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

When users try and open the preferences screen on older devices, I get an exception that reads:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mridang.stupidapp.Settings.getFragmentManager
at com.mridang.stupidapp.Settings.onCreate(Settings.java:15)
```

How should I modify my preferences screen to work with older devices i.e. API 8? Thanks.

Comment: I've made a library for this here: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MaterialPreferenceLibrary .  Also, I'm not sure, but I think that Google allows something too: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/9kZ3SsXdT2T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither ActionBarSherlock nor the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) provides support for Preference Fragments.

You need to revert to Perference Activities as explained in the [Settings Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html).

There are a few old questions that discuss the same topic:

- [PreferenceActivity Android 4.0 and earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186697/preferenceactivity-android-4-0-and-earlier)
- [Was PreferenceFragment intentionally excluded from the compatibility package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501431/was-preferencefragment-intentionally-excluded-from-the-compatibility-package)