# How could I use the same set of preference screens for all Android versions from 2.X to 4.X?

Tags: android, compatibility, android-preferences, backwards-compatibility

**NOTICE: Please save yourself some time and refer to the accepted answer, no need to read all the quesiton.**
You may read the rest of the question and the answer I provided for an alternative (although less sophisticated) method.
Also, you may want to take advantage of the fix for the background glitch in Android 2.X, by adding the related piece of code to your preference activity class.

**Background**
Being a newbie to Android coding, but somewhat experienced in other programming languages/frameworks, I was expecting my walk to Android application coding would be a rather pleasant one. It was so, until I stumbled upon this problem:

Eclipse wizard for Android projects suggested I could reach a 95% of devices if I set my minimum API to 8 (Android 2.2). I didn't need to do any fancy things with my app anyways, so I thought, "sure, why not?". Everything was okay, except occasionally I'd find several methods/classes that were deprecated in most recent API versions, and so I had to devise ways to keep using the old ways for old devices, and try to use as much as possible the new ways for newer Android versions. This is one such occasion.

After using the Eclipse wizard for creating a preference activity, I realized that the Eclipse precompiler/parser/checker(or whatever it's called) Lint, would complain about not being able to use the new ways of creating/managing preferences in older API versions. So I thought, "all right, screw the new ways. Let's do it old way and since new API versions are supposed to be backward-compatible, it should be okay", but it wasn't. Old way used methods/classes that are marked as deprecated; which, to me, means, even though they'd still work in current API, they'd stop working at some point in future releases.

So I started searching for the right way to do this, and finally hit this page: [What to use instead of "addPreferencesFromResource" in a PreferenceActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822319/what-to-use-instead-of-addpreferencesfromresource-in-a-preferenceactivity) where Garret Wilson, explains a way to use old preference screen resources in a way compatible with the new ways. It was great, and finally had the feeling I could move on with my app coding, except it wouldn't work when targeting older APIs, as it was using newer APIs code. So I had to devise a way to make it work for both old APIs and newer. After tinkering with it for a while I managed to find a way, by using precompiler(or whatever it's called) annotations and the great getClass().getMethod() along with exceptions.

Everything seemed to work flawlessly until I created a preference sub-screen. It was displaying correctly in newer Android versions, but when I tried in older ones, I could merely see a black screen. After much searching, I found this page which explains the issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4611 This is apparently a known glitch that's been around several Android versions for a good while. I read the whole thread and found several proposed solutions to the problem, but I really didn't like entirely any of them. I, for one, prefer to avoid as much static stuff as I can, and do things programmatically. I prefer automation over repetitive work. Some solutions suggested to create sub-screens as parent screens, then adding them onto the manifest file, and calling them from the parent screen through an intent. I'd really hate having to keep track of those things: entries in manifest, separated screen resource file, intents... So that was a no-no for me. I kept looking and found a programmatic approach I liked much better... only to find that it didn't work. It consisted of iterating through the whole view tree of the preference screen and assigning a proper background to preference sub-screens, but it just didn't work because, as I later found out after much debugging, preference sub-screens views are not a child of preference screen views. I had to find a way to achieve this myself. I tried as many things as I could think of, researched and researched to no avail. I was at the verge of abandoning at several occasions, but after some two weeks of continued effort and much debugging I found a workaround, which I posted in comment #35.

**Opinion**
It really isn't the perfect solution/approach, and I'm aware of several of its drawbacks, but it's one that works, so I decided I would share it. Hopefully I'm not being too ridiculous in my enthusiasm to share what has taken me what I'd consider quite a lot of effort, as I'm aware it's not that great of an issue, that any experienced coder could solve. But hey, I think sharing knowledge makes me a bit better, no matter how much I brag, than an experienced coder who keeps everything to himself. Just sharing my opinion, because I can't believe nobody ever had this problem before, but I do believe many have had it and didn't bother to share their knowledge.

I present you in the answer with a proposed class to use over several versions of Android, and some suggestions on its usage. I'm open to discussion and contributions to make it a better class.

**Known issues:**

- Parent screen Decor view background is cloned onto child screen Decor view background, which apparently isn't the normal behavior.
  *Status: dismissed until somebody comes up with a good reason to fix this*
- Crashes upon screen rotation
  *Status: Fixed.

  Probably related to resource visibility by newer API implementation (inner class PF)

  Apparently inherited classes from preferenceFragment need to have all their members static. I guess it makes sense if you're supposed to inherit every time you need to use a new fragment*

Comment: Or you download the latest ADT plugin, and make a new PreferenceActivity. It takes care of being compatible with both high and low API versions.

Comment: @A--C I just tried again and realized it actually works, no matter the 9 warnings I got after using the SettingsActivity wizard. I guess when I first tried I saw all the warnings and the so many files it created and passed onto thinking there should be a simpler way to add preferences. Although not exact, this is what I meant by: "After using the Eclipse wizard for creating a preference activity, I realized that the Eclipse precompiler/parser/checker(or whatever it's called) Lint, would complain about not being able to use the new ways of creating/managing preferences in older API versions."

Comment: Oh well, at least I found a workaround for the graphics glitch in preference sub-screen in 2.x. I guess they didn't include a preference sub-screen in the example for this reason? Anyways, I might as well stick to my class, as it looks neater and cleaner, even though it can't work with fragments... or I might end up getting used to working with fragments in the end, who knows :) Anyways, too late not to feel embarrassed but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It's always nice to have multiple ways of doing something and you got more familiar with the API stuff :) And as you said, you fixed something, even better!

Comment: @A--C If you'd like to make your first comment an answer, I'd like to accept it as the valid answer. Then I can edit my question and point people straight to your answer, I wouldn't want to mislead anyone.

Comment: Or you could edit your answer, putting something about the new ADT plugin PreferenceActivity at the top and leave everything else the way it is. Then just accept your own answer, you're allowed to do that and techincally it's right either way - I just provided an alternative.

Comment: I know, but yours should be the accepted answer. It's simple and straightforward, thus you deserve the points, and users deserve to be taken to it without the stress that encountering a big block of text represents. Please, will you?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are on the latest ADT plugin, there is an option to easily create a preference Activity that supports most older Android versions as well as all the new ones.

> Right click on your project -> Other -> Android Activity

Then choose SettingsActivity
[image]

The Activity created will take take care of working with both high and low API versions since it uses if statements to choose the appropriate method of displaying the preferences.

---

**EDIT** 
A good point was brought up: Phone-Sized devices, regardless of API version use the old `PreferenceActivity` methods.

The quickest way to get API 11+ devices to use `Fragments` is to remove `!isXLargeTablet(context);` from `isSimplePreferences()`

```
private static boolean isSimplePreferences(Context context) {
    return ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS
            || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
}
```

However, now the user has more navigation to do.
[image: Headers as root]

This is because `onBuildHeaders()` is called.

To get rid of this, we will need to make our own PreferenceFragment that adds each xml resource.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class AllPreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragment{
        @Override
        public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

            // Add 'notifications' preferences, and a corresponding header.
            PreferenceCategory fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(getActivity());
            fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_notifications);
            getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);

            // Add 'data and sync' preferences, and a corresponding header.
            fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(getActivity());
            fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_data_sync);
            getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_data_sync);

            // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences to
            // their values. When their values change, their summaries are updated
            // to reflect the new value, per the Android Design guidelines.
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_new_message_ringtone"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("sync_frequency"));
        }
    }
```

If you can determine the screen size from outside the `Activity` that launches the settings, you can specify a fragment for it to launch via `EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT`

```
i.putExtra(SettingsActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT, "com.example.test.SettingsActivity$AllPreferencesFragment");
```

Or you can have the `SettingsActivity` determine whether or not to show this Fragment (assuming you're happy with the `isXLargeTablet()` method.

Change `onBuildHeaders()` to:

```
@Override
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    if (!isSimplePreferences(this) && isXLargeTablet(this)) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }
}
```

Add this method:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupNewApiPhoneSizePreferences() {
    if (!isXLargeTablet(this) && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new AllPreferencesFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

And in `onPostCreate()` add the method call.

```
setupNewApiPhoneSizePreferences();
```

This should now use non-deprecated calls from API 11 onwards.

Comment: Having done so the first thing that happened to me was I got some warnings about deprecated methods: `addPreferencesFromResource`, `getPreferenceScreen` and `findPreference`. Is this intended?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Yes, some parts of the code use the `PreferenceActivity`methods (specifically in `setupSimplePreferencesScreen()`)

Comment: Then it doesn't feel right to use those methods for the newer APIs.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I will update my answer soon to add information about changing the code slightly to use Fragments on new devices (as in new API) with phone-size screens.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this class to display a preference screen in all Android versions from 2.X to 4.X, by feeding it with a preference screen resource.

You may use it directly by renaming it if you like, but I'd suggest you to add it to your project as is, and inherit from it, which is much cleaner if you need to work with several parent preference screens.

If you'd like to use it directly, just replace prefs value with your preference screen resource ID.

If you'd like to inherit from it, you should do it like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyPreferencesActivity extends CompatiblePreferenceActivity
{   
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        setPrefs(R.xml.mypreferencesactivity);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }   
}
```

ALWAYS call setPrefs(int) before calling super.onCreate(Bundle)

If, for some reason, you'd just like to take advantage of the glitch-fix and create preferences on your own, you may either just copy the glitch-fix code into your own preference activity, or inherit from the class and catch the PrefsNotSet exception as follows:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyPreferencesActivity extends CompatiblePreferenceActivity
{   
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        try{
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }catch(PrefsNotSetException e){};
    }   
}
```

**And finally, the class:**

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceScreen;

public class CompatiblePreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity
{
    private int prefs=0;

    //Get/Set
    public void setPrefs(int prefs)
    {
        this.prefs=prefs;
    }

    //Exception
    protected static class PrefsNotSetException extends RuntimeException
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        PrefsNotSetException()
        {
            super("\"prefs\" should be set to a valid preference resource ID.");
        }
    }

    //Creation
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (prefs==0)
            throw new PrefsNotSetException();
        else
            try {
                getClass().getMethod("getFragmentManager");
                AddResourceApi11AndGreater();
                }
            catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { //Api < 11
                    AddResourceApiLessThan11();
                }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void AddResourceApiLessThan11()
    {
        addPreferencesFromResource(prefs);
    }

    @TargetApi(11)
    protected void AddResourceApi11AndGreater()
    {
        PF.prefs=prefs;
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(
            android.R.id.content, new PF()).commit();
    }

    @TargetApi(11)
    public static class PF extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        private static int prefs;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(prefs);
        }
    }

    //Sub-screen background glitch fix
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen,
        Preference preference)
    {
        super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);
        if (preference!=null)
            if (preference instanceof PreferenceScreen)
                if (((PreferenceScreen)preference).getDialog()!=null)
                    ((PreferenceScreen)preference).getDialog().
                        getWindow().getDecorView().
                        setBackgroundDrawable(this.getWindow().
                            getDecorView().getBackground().getConstantState().
                            newDrawable());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: how to handle clicks of preferences as findPreferences is also deprecated

Comment: this is failing on 4.4

Answer (score 1):

Well, working with the autogenerated SettingsActivity got pretty old pretty quickly. One has to scroll up and down past boilerplate code - moreover it's full of yellow warnings and I hate yellow (deprecated warnings can't be avoided altogether though - see [What to use instead of "addPreferencesFromResource" in a PreferenceActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822319/what-to-use-instead-of-addpreferencesfromresource-in-a-preferenceactivity), where also the matter of how to make cross API `PreferenceActivity` is touched also - and [Was PreferenceFragment intentionally excluded from the compatibility package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501431/was-preferencefragment-intentionally-excluded-from-the-compatibility-package) for a discussion). And also you may easily get an NPE - did you know that `onPostCreate()` is actually `onPostStart()` - so `findPreference()` returns `null` in `onStart()`.

Now there are solutions involving reflection but reflection is to be avoided (like hell it is) - and since we are not interested in pre 2 versions of android reflection *can* be avoided (see [Is checking SDK_INT enough or is lazy loading needed for using newer android APIs ? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271593/is-checking-sdk-int-enough-or-is-lazy-loading-needed-for-using-newer-android-api)). Also there are solutions involving choosing a class at runtime - but having 2 classes sucks and is not OOP anyways (for those and other solutions see the answer to related question: [PreferenceActivity Android 4.0 and earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186697/preferenceactivity-android-4-0-and-earlier)).

So I came up with an abstract base class, which is the correct Java and OO way of doing things (except if you need Eclair and below where you do need reflection and/or lazy loading of classes to avoid `VerifyErrors`), where I moved the autogenerated boilerplate code:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * A {@link PreferenceActivity} that presents a set of application settings. On
 * handset devices, settings are presented as a single list. On tablets,
 * settings are split by category, with category headers shown to the left of
 * the list of settings.
 * <p>
 * See <a href="http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html">
 * Android Design: Settings</a> for design guidelines and the <a
 * href="http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html">Settings
 * API Guide</a> for more information on developing a Settings UI.
 *
 * Defines two abstract methods that need be implemented by implementators.
 */
public abstract class BaseSettings extends PreferenceActivity {

    /**
     * Determines whether to always show the simplified settings UI, where
     * settings are presented in a single list. When false, settings are shown
     * as a master/detail two-pane view on tablets. When true, a single pane is
     * shown on tablets.
     */
    private static final boolean ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS = false;

    /**
     * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
     * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
                Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
                >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public final boolean onIsMultiPane() { // never used by us
        return isXLargeTablet(this) && !isSimplePreferences(this);
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether the simplified settings UI should be shown. This is
     * true if this is forced via {@link #ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS}, or the device
     * doesn't have newer APIs like {@link PreferenceFragment}, or the device
     * doesn't have an extra-large screen. In these cases, a single-pane
     * "simplified" settings UI should be shown.
     */
    private static final boolean isSimplePreferences(Context context) {
        return ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS
            || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB
            || !isXLargeTablet(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // disallow onCreate(), see comment in onPostCreate()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected final void onStart() {
        // disallow onStart(), see comment in onPostCreate()
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // onPostCreate() probably is needed because onBuildHeaders() is called
        // after onCreate() ? This piece of err code should be called
        // onPostStart() btw - so yeah
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupSimplePreferencesScreen();
        // findPreference will return null if setupSimplePreferencesScreen
        // hasn't run, so I disallow onCreate() and onStart()
    }

    /**
     * Shows the simplified settings UI if the device configuration if the
     * device configuration dictates that a simplified, single-pane UI should be
     * shown.
     */
    private void setupSimplePreferencesScreen() {
        if (!isSimplePreferences(this)) {
            return;
        }
        buildSimplePreferences();
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    /*
     * Subclasses of PreferenceActivity should implement onBuildHeaders(List) to
     * populate the header list with the desired items. Doing this implicitly
     * switches the class into its new "headers + fragments" mode rather than
     * the old style of just showing a single preferences list (from
     * http://developer
     * .android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) -> IE
     * this is called automatically - reads the R.xml.pref_headers and creates
     * the 2 panes view - it was driving me mad - @inheritDoc my - It does not
     * crash in Froyo cause isSimplePreferences is always true for
     * Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB - @Override has
     * nothing to do with runtime and of course on Froyo this is never called by
     * the system
     */
    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public final void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        if (!isSimplePreferences(this)) {
            loadHeadersFromResource(getHeadersXmlID(), target);
        }
    }

    // =========================================================================
    // Abstract API
    // =========================================================================
    /**
     * Must return an id for the headers xml file. There you define the headers
     * and the corresponding PreferenceFragment for each header which you must
     * of course implement. This is used in the super implementation of
     * {@link #onBuildHeaders(List)}
     *
     * @return an id from the R file for the xml containing the headers
     */
    abstract int getHeadersXmlID();

    /**
     * Builds a pre Honeycomb preference screen. An implementation would use the
     * (deprecated)
*{@link android.preference.PreferenceActivity#addPreferencesFromResource(int)}
     */
    abstract void buildSimplePreferences();
}
```

And a sample implementation:

```
public final class SettingsActivity extends BaseSettings implements
        OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private static final int PREF_HEADERS_XML = R.xml.pref_headers;
    private static CharSequence master_enable;
    private OnPreferenceChangeListener listener;
    private static Preference master_pref;
    private static final String TAG = SettingsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private SharedPreferences sp;
    /** Used as canvas for the simple preferences screen */
    private static final int EMPTY_PREF_RESOURCE = R.xml.pref_empty;
    private static int PREF_RESOURCE_SETTINGS = R.xml.pref_data_sync;

    // abstract overrides   
    @Override
    int getHeadersXmlID() {
        return PREF_HEADERS_XML;
    }

    @Override
    void buildSimplePreferences() {
        // In the simplified UI, fragments are not used at all and we instead
        // use the older PreferenceActivity APIs.
        // THIS is a blank preferences layout - which I need so
        // getPreferenceScreen() does not return null - so I can add a header -
        // alternatively you can very well comment everything out apart from
        // addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_data_sync);
        addPreferencesFromResource(EMPTY_PREF_RESOURCE);
        // Add 'data and sync' preferences, and a corresponding header.
        PreferenceCategory fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(this);
        fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_data_sync);
        getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
        addPreferencesFromResource(PREF_RESOURCE_SETTINGS);
    }

    // here is the work done
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        master_enable = getResources().getText(
            R.string.enable_monitoring_master_pref_key);
        listener = new ToggleMonitoringListener();
        // DefaultSharedPreferences - register listener lest Monitor aborts
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        master_pref = findPreference(master_enable.toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        master_pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(listener); // no way to
        // unregister, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20493608/281545 This
        // listener reacts to *manual* updates - so no need to be active
        // outside onResume()/onPause()
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // may not be called (as onDestroy() is killable), but no leak,
        // see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20493608/281545
        sp.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /**
     * Toggles monitoring and sets the preference summary.Triggered on *manual*
     * update of the *single* preference it is registered with, but before this
     * preference is updated and saved.
     */
    private static class ToggleMonitoringListener implements
            OnPreferenceChangeListener {

        ToggleMonitoringListener() {}

        @Override
        public boolean
                onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            if (newValue instanceof Boolean) {
                final boolean enable = (Boolean) newValue;
                Monitor.enableMonitoring(preference.getContext(), enable);
                final CheckBoxPreference p = (CheckBoxPreference) preference;
                preference.setSummary((enable) ? p.getSummaryOn() : p
                    .getSummaryOff());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This fragment is used when the activity is showing a two-pane
     * settings UI.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public final static class DataSyncPreferenceFragment extends
            PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.w(TAG, "onCreate");
            addPreferencesFromResource(PREF_RESOURCE_SETTINGS);
            master_pref = findPreference(master_enable.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key) {
        if (master_enable == null || master_pref == null) return;
        if (master_enable.toString().equals(key)) {
            refreshMasterPreference();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param key
     */
    private void refreshMasterPreference() {
        final Boolean isMonitoringEnabled = AccessPreferences.get(this,
            master_enable.toString(), false);
        Log.w(TAG, "Stored value: " + isMonitoringEnabled);
        final CheckBoxPreference p = (CheckBoxPreference) master_pref;
        final boolean needsRefresh = p.isChecked() != isMonitoringEnabled;
        if (needsRefresh) {
            p.setChecked(isMonitoringEnabled);
            p.setSummary((isMonitoringEnabled) ? p.getSummaryOn() : p
                .getSummaryOff());
        }
    }
}
```

So the main idea is you provide an xml for preferences with headers:

```
    public final void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        if (!isSimplePreferences(this)) {
            loadHeadersFromResource(getHeadersXmlID(), target);
        }
    }
```

where:

```
    @Override
    int getHeadersXmlID() {
        return PREF_HEADERS_XML;
    }
```

and `PREF_HEADERS_XML`:

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- These settings headers are only used on tablets. -->
    <header
        android:fragment=".activities.SettingsActivity$DataSyncPreferenceFragment"
        android:title="@string/pref_header_data_sync" />
</preference-headers>
```

and setting up the simple preferences in `buildSimplePreferences()`

I am interested into making this into a more general API - probably including the `sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener` - so ideas welcome.

Ah, yes, the sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener fluff:

```
// FLUFF AHEAD:
// the fluff that follows is for binding preference summary to value -
// essentially wrappers around OnPreferenceChangeListener - just so
// you get an idea of the mess this autogenerated piece of, code, was
// formatter:off
/**
 * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
 * to reflect its new value.
 */
/* private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener
        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener =
        new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                            Object value) {
            String stringValue = value.toString();
            if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                // For list preferences, look up the correct display value
                // in the preference's 'entries' list.
                ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
                // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
                preference.setSummary(index >= 0
                        ? listPreference.getEntries()[index] : null);
            } else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
                // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display
                // value using RingtoneManager.
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                    // Empty values correspond to 'silent' (no ringtone).
                    // preference.setSummary(R.string.pref_ringtone_silent);
                } else {
                    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                        preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));
                    if (ringtone == null) {
                        // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
                        preference.setSummary(null);
                    } else {
                        // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone
                        // display name.
                        String name = ringtone
                            .getTitle(preference.getContext());
                        preference.setSummary(name);
                    }
                }
            } else if (preference instanceof CheckBoxPreference) {
                boolean b = (Boolean) value;
                Log.w(TAG, "::::value " + b);
                final CheckBoxPreference p =(CheckBoxPreference)preference;
                preference.setSummary((b) ? p.getSummaryOn() : p
                    .getSummaryOff());
                Log.w(TAG, p.getKey() + " :: " + p.isChecked());
            } else {
                // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
                // simple string representation.
                preference.setSummary(stringValue);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }; */

/**
 * Binds a preference's summary to its value. More specifically, when the
 * preference's value is changed, its summary (line of text below the
 * preference title) is updated to reflect the value. The summary is also
 * immediately updated upon calling this method. The exact display format is
 * dependent on the type of preference.
 *
 * @see #sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
 */
/* private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference
      .setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);
    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(
        preference,
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
            preference.getContext()).getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
} */
```