# SettingsActivity crashing when pressing Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I'm working on a project that requires a settings menu.

My code shows no errors, but yet when I try to press the Filter fragment in the app, it crashes. I'm relatively new to Android so I have no idea what I might be doing wrong... Here's my code:

```
protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
    return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || GeneralPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || DataSyncPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || NotificationPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || ProfilePreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || FilterPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || PrivacyPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
}
```

Here's the class for the Filter fragment:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class FilterPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_filter);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_switch_rest"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_switch_vend"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_switch_show"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<SwitchPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="example_switch_rest"
    android:summary="@string/pref_description_restaurant"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_restaurants" />
<SwitchPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="example_switch_vend"
    android:summary="@string/pref_description_vending"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_vending" />
<SwitchPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="example_switch_show"
    android:summary="@string/pref_description_shows"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_shows" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

This is the error log:

```
01-04 13:37:55.864 2828-2828/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
01-04 13:37:55.866 2828-2828/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
01-04 13:37:55.879 2828-2828/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
01-04 13:37:55.895 2828-2828/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-04 13:37:55.895 2828-2828/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-04 13:37:55.896 2828-2828/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
01-04 13:37:55.908 2828-2828/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
01-04 13:37:55.913 1300-1453/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.gijbelssiemen.list appid=10056 user=0: from pid 2828
01-04 13:37:55.921 2828-2828/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-04 13:37:55.931 2828-2835/? E/art: Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_1
01-04 13:37:55.931 2828-2835/? I/AndroidRuntime: NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_1' failed
01-04 13:37:56.460 2840-2840/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
01-04 13:37:56.461 2840-2840/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
01-04 13:37:56.486 2840-2840/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
01-04 13:37:56.492 2836-2836/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
01-04 13:37:56.493 2836-2836/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
01-04 13:37:56.512 2836-2836/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
01-04 13:37:56.525 2836-2836/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-04 13:37:56.526 2836-2836/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-04 13:37:56.527 2836-2836/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
01-04 13:37:56.535 2840-2840/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-04 13:37:56.535 2840-2840/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-04 13:37:56.536 2840-2840/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
01-04 13:37:56.546 2836-2836/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.wm.Wm
01-04 13:37:56.548 2836-2836/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-04 13:37:56.555 2836-2852/? E/art: Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_2
01-04 13:37:56.555 2836-2852/? I/AndroidRuntime: NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_2' failed
01-04 13:37:56.567 2840-2840/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
01-04 13:37:56.576 1300-1389/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.gijbelssiemen.list/.SettingsActivity} from uid 0 on display 0
01-04 13:37:56.610 2840-2840/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-04 13:37:56.618 1300-1882/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 2855:com.gijbelssiemen.list/u0a56 for activity com.gijbelssiemen.list/.SettingsActivity
01-04 13:37:56.628 2855-2855/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-04 13:37:56.653 2855-2855/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.gijbelssiemen.list-2/lib/x86
01-04 13:37:56.693 952-1355/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
01-04 13:37:56.695 2855-2868/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-04 13:37:56.813 2855-2868/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-04 13:37:56.850 2855-2868/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-04 13:37:56.850 2855-2868/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabfaeb20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-04 13:37:57.044 2046-2063/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab813fb0
01-04 13:37:57.345 1300-1319/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.gijbelssiemen.list/.SettingsActivity: +738ms
01-04 13:38:04.887 1300-1312/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.gijbelssiemen.list/.SettingsActivity (has extras)} from uid 10056 on display 0
01-04 13:38:04.944 2855-2855/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-04 13:38:04.944 2855-2855/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.gijbelssiemen.list, PID: 2855
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gijbelssiemen.list/com.gijbelssiemen.list.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                                                 at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:225)
                                                 at com.gijbelssiemen.list.SettingsActivity.bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(SettingsActivity.java:116)
                                                 at com.gijbelssiemen.list.SettingsActivity.access$000(SettingsActivity.java:36)
                                                 at com.gijbelssiemen.list.SettingsActivity$FilterPreferenceFragment.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:297)
                                                 at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2198)
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
                                                 at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
                                                 at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6252)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
01-04 13:38:04.945 1300-1311/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.gijbelssiemen.list/.SettingsActivity
01-04 13:38:04.950 1300-1311/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.gijbelssiemen.list/.SettingsActivity
01-04 13:38:04.995 1300-1349/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-04 13:38:05.015 1300-1349/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-04 13:38:05.015 1300-1349/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9c611180, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-04 13:38:05.459 1300-1314/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{18dec05 u0 com.gijbelssiemen.list/.SettingsActivity t40 f}
01-04 13:38:05.498 2046-2063/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-04 13:38:05.518 2046-2063/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-04 13:38:05.518 2046-2063/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa417f0c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

If I forgot to include anything, please tell me! Thanks!

Comment: post your error log too

Comment: where is your logcat ?

Comment: @VivekMishra posted that too!

Comment: error is described clearly in your logcat 


`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gijbelssiemen.list/com.gijbelssiemen.list.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it's posted now!

Comment: @VivekMishra could you help me resolve this? I don't really know what it means

Comment: `at com.gijbelssiemen.list.SettingsActivity.bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(SettingsActivity.java:116)`
Here is the problem you are casting a boolean value to string

Comment: I have the same problem and I just added the Settings Activity with Android Studio and changed booleans name, it has no sense. I have cleared shared preferences, deleted the data, deleted and reinstalled the app... what can I do?

Comment: There is an answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157332/default-bindpreferencesummarytovalue-crashes-for-non-string-types It worked for me