# findPreference() in PreferenceActivity throwing NPE Android?

Tags: android, preferences, preferenceactivity

I created my own custom `PreferenceActivity` using answer of Kevin Remo from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076073/how-could-i-use-the-same-set-of-preference-screens-for-all-android-versions-from). This code doesn't have `onPreferenceClickListener` so I add in `onResume` of my activity. It works fine on API 9 but fails on API 19.

Below is my activity code.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SettingsActivity extends CompatiblePreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setPrefs(R.xml.user_settings);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context,
            AttributeSet attrs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        Preference logout = (Preference) findPreference("preflogout");
        logout.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), preference.getKey(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
                // open browser or intent here
            }
        });
        CheckBoxPreference notification = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("prefpushnotification");
        notification
                .setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                        CheckBoxPreference notification1 = (CheckBoxPreference) preference;
                        if (notification1.isChecked()) {
                            notification1.setSummary("Notification is on");
                        } else {
                            notification1.setSummary("Notification is off");
                        }
                        return false;
                        // open browser or intent here
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.user_setting, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

In onResume I am using findPreferences() which gives NPE on API 19 but works on API9.

This is custom preference activity class i used which supports 2x to 4x version as said in answer to link.

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceScreen;

public class CompatiblePreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    private int prefs = 0;

    // Get/Set
    public void setPrefs(int prefs) {
        this.prefs = prefs;
    }

    // Exception
    protected static class PrefsNotSetException extends RuntimeException {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        PrefsNotSetException() {
            super("\"prefs\" should be set to a valid preference resource ID.");
        }
    }

    // Creation
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (prefs == 0)
            throw new PrefsNotSetException();
        else
            try {
                getClass().getMethod("getFragmentManager");
                AddResourceApi11AndGreater();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { // Api < 11
                AddResourceApiLessThan11();
            }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void AddResourceApiLessThan11() {
        addPreferencesFromResource(prefs);
    }

    @TargetApi(11)
    protected void AddResourceApi11AndGreater() {
        PF.prefs = prefs;
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new PF()).commit();
    }

    @TargetApi(11)
    public static class PF extends PreferenceFragment {
        private static int prefs;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(prefs);
        }
    }

    // Sub-screen background glitch fix
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen,
            Preference preference) {
        super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);
        if (preference != null)
            if (preference instanceof PreferenceScreen)
                if (((PreferenceScreen) preference).getDialog() != null)
                    ((PreferenceScreen) preference)
                            .getDialog()
                            .getWindow()
                            .getDecorView()
                            .setBackgroundDrawable(
                                    this.getWindow().getDecorView()
                                            .getBackground().getConstantState()
                                            .newDrawable());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
02-13 19:54:08.222: E/AndroidRuntime(4282): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.buzzreel/com.buzzreel.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 19:54:08.222: E/AndroidRuntime(4282):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2774)
02-13 19:54:08.222: E/AndroidRuntime(4282):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
02-13 19:54:08.222: E/AndroidRuntime(4282):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2238)
02-13 19:54:08.222: E/AndroidRuntime(4282):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-13 19:54:08.222: E/AndroidRuntime(4282):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-13 19:54:08.222: E/AndroidRuntime(4282):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-13 19:54:08.222: E/AndroidRuntime(4282):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-13 19:54:08.222: E/AndroidRuntime(4282):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
02-13 19:54:08.222: E/AndroidRuntime(4282):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 19:54:08.222: E/AndroidRuntime(4282):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-13 19:54:08.222: E/AndroidRuntime(4282):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
02-13 19:54:08.222: E/AndroidRuntime(4282):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
02-13 19:54:08.222: E/AndroidRuntime(4282):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-13 19:54:08.222: E/AndroidRuntime(4282): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 19:54:08.222: E/AndroidRuntime(4282):     at com.buzzreel.SettingsActivity.onResume(SettingsActivity.java:42)
02-13 19:54:08.222: E/AndroidRuntime(4282):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
02-13 19:54:08.222: E/AndroidRuntime(4282):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5310)
```

Comment: Which line is line 42 of `SettingsActivity`?

Comment: One with findpreference() in onResume of SettingsActivity

Comment: Are you sure? There is no dereferencing in either of those lines, and the `findPreference` method source code indicates it cannot throw a NPE.

Comment: @stkent this line 

  Preference logout = (Preference) findPreference("preflogout");
        logout.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), preference.getKey(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false; 
                // open browser or intent here 
            } 
        });

logout variable comes null.

Comment: I wonder if the call `Preference logout = (Preference) findPreference("preflogout");` needs to be replaced with `Preference logout = (Preference) myPreferencesFragment.findPreference("preflogout");` on API levels greater than 11. Try that and see if it works.