# Better way of upping my Minimum API Level?

Tags: android, api, sdk, android-fragments, android-preferences

So I just had to up my min API level to 11 for the Preference (addpreferenceresource was depreciated) - turns out 9-10 takes out like 50% of the market. So my question is, is it better to just suppress the warning to cater to the Gingerbread market or is there a different way to make my preference reference without using Preference Fragments?

Comment: Why not use the Eclipse-provided settings Activity? And as @wtsang02 said, deprecated doesn't mean non-usable. In fact, you have to use the "deprecated as of 3.0" methods in 2.3 < since there are no fragments there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would implement both types (the one that works in 11+ and the one that works in 10-), then use conditional checks for them. This is written in quite a bit of detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258323/1438733).

Basically, you end up setting up `OtherPreferencesActivity` with `PreferenceFragment`, and then `PreferencesActivity` with the deprecated `PreferenceActivity`. *(Your APK will not break by including this deprecated code, as long as you use a version check so that if/when it's removed in the future, it doesn't try to find it.)*

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, PreferencesActivity.class);
} else {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, OtherPreferencesActivity.class);
}
```

Keep in mind, you will want to have them use each others' methods as much as possible so that you don't end up duplicating code.

Last tip: `@TargetApi(11)` and `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` will come in handy here. Just **be careful** that you're not ignoring other deprecations by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

"depreciated" doesn't mean you can't use it and will break your system if you run the code. It means that it is officially  not recommended to use and this method maybe removed from the api. In the future but we don't know when. So I would say it is save to use in this case for now.