# android preferences under different versions

Tags: android, deprecated, preferenceactivity

I am writing an Android app with preferences.
I have `minSdkVersion="7"` and `android:targetSdkVersion="17"` 
Should I use `PreferenceActivity` or `PreferenceFragment` or maybe together to make it work on android from `2.1` to `4.2`? When I use `PreferenceActivity` Eclipse tells me `The method addPreferencesFromResource(int) from the type PreferenceActivity is deprecated`

Comment: I believe, you need to use PreferenceActivity since you are planning to support from version 2.1. Let us wait for expert thoughts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use deprecated methods. It's only warning. If you want, you can find actual method in android documentation but this isn't good approach, because this method can not run on older devices.  I hope I helped

Comment: but my app crashes on Android 4.2

Comment: deprecated means that the method will not run on newer device

Answer (score 0):

You should use both `PreferenceActivity` and `PreferenceFragment` because `PreferenceFragment` is supported on API 11 onward and isn't available on Support Library. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501431/was-preferencefragment-intentionally-excluded-from-the-compatibility-package).