# How to replace a view using android.support package?

Tags: android, fragment, android-preferences, android-support-library

I am attempting to replace a view in my MainActivity so that as soon as the application opens,  my preferences fragment appears.  Everything was working until I attempted to accomplish the same task using the android.support.v4.app.Fragment library to support devices of API level 10.  On my .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()) call, I get the following error: "The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, SettingsFragment)".  I do not know why this is an issue, because my settings fragment extends PreferenceFragment which extends Fragment.

All help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()) //SettingFragment is my class that manages the preferences
    .commit();

     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainService.class);
     startService(intent); 
    return super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
}

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Next Class:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment{

ListPreference notificationDrawerUnitOfMeasurePreference;
ListPreference notificationAreaUnitOfMeasurePreference;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    notificationDrawerUnitOfMeasurePreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("pref_key_measurement_unit");
    notificationAreaUnitOfMeasurePreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("pref_key_measurement_unit_notification_area");

    notificationDrawerUnitOfMeasurePreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(notificationDrawerUnitOfMeasurePreferenceListener);
    notificationAreaUnitOfMeasurePreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(notificationAreaUnitOfMeasurePreferenceListener);

    notificationDrawerUnitOfMeasurePreference.setSummary(notificationDrawerUnitOfMeasurePreference.getValue().toString());
    notificationAreaUnitOfMeasurePreference.setSummary(notificationAreaUnitOfMeasurePreference.getValue().toString());
}

private OnPreferenceChangeListener notificationDrawerUnitOfMeasurePreferenceListener = new OnPreferenceChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        ((ListPreference) preference).setValue(newValue.toString());
        preference.setSummary(newValue.toString());
        return false;
    }


};

private OnPreferenceChangeListener notificationAreaUnitOfMeasurePreferenceListener = new OnPreferenceChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        ((ListPreference) preference).setValue(newValue.toString());
        preference.setSummary(newValue.toString());
        return false;
    }


};


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that your SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment which is not in the compatibility library. So when it's saying that your method call is "not applicable for the arguments (int, SettingsFragment)" it means that it expects a support.v4.app.Fragment and you're giving it an android.app.Fragment.

Unfortunately, to date, there has been no movement on Google to add PreferenceFragment to the compatibility library.

A very thorough discussion on the PreferenceFragment and the compatibility library can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501646/417426).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response Kris.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Kris, PreferenceFragment is not yet a part of the compatibility library. Until that happens, you can use a library like [UnifiedPreferences](https://github.com/saik0/UnifiedPreference)