# How to use preference fragment in android api 8

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-compatibility, android-support-library

i'm implementing viewpager in my app, it has 4 tabs. In the last tab i want to implement settings. If i look at the [preferencefragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) its not supported for devices below API 11. Even in android compat lib v7 also, this feature is not included. Looked at few alternatives like 3rd party libs which are not official. What is the best, efficient way to use this?

Comment: For lack of a better answer, please look at the answer by Commons on this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501431/was-preferencefragment-intentionally-excluded-from-the-compatibility-package

Comment: Thanks, i tried till now, i'm confused about the implementation, can you provide any working example code. 3